# Will it affect anything if I delete site from site content and structure?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, sub-site

I have currently removed some subsites on a site in the SharePoint. For example, I have a site called "sample 1" and there are another 15 subsites inside "sample 1" but I actually only needed 9 subsites. So I have deleted the other 6 subsites that I didn't want from the "sample 1" site.

It looked like this worked as only 9 subsites were on "sample 1". But, when I went to site content and structure, there were still 15 sites under "sample 1". I want everything to look nice and neat, so I also removed the subsites from site content and structure.

Will it affect anything if I delete the subsites completely from site content and structure? Hope you guys can give me some advice, thank you.[image]

Answer (score 2):

**As a short answer** , No effect , it's the same method of .

- Go to sub-site setting > Site Action  > delete this site.

But I suggest to you , if you will need this site in the future you can hide it only from `Navigation` settings below `look and feel` in site setting .

Meanwhile , If you don't need this site forever you can delete it with any method with **the same result** :

- Content And Structure .
- Go to sub-site setting > Site Action  > delete this site.

That will be recycled on **Admin recycle bin** , and to can restore it Navigate to

```
http://sitecollection/_layouts/15/AdminRecycleBin.aspx?View=2
```

Comment: There are 15 image hyperlinks on "sample 1", I have deleted away 6 image hyperlink. So, on the "sample 1", i will only those 9 image hyperlink (9 sub sites) that i want.  However, it still can see the 15 sub sites when i go to site content and structure. I only can delete from site content and structure. How can I delete them away without effect anything?

Comment: If I want to hide the site, how can I hide it? As in I only find the sub sites under site content and structure, I have removed them on "sample 1", so now I cannot open those sub sites that I deleted from 'sample 1' and it still can see those sub sites on site content and structure. Thus, your method may not work for me if I want to hide the sub sites. Is there other ways? Please kindly advice.

Comment: Hi, I added a picture just now. It is a site content and structure image and now I only can remove those sub sites from here as in it still can see the name even though I removed from my site "sample 1". So how should I remove them from site content and structure? For example, I want to remove 'blog example' (in red), is it just select the site then click on action and delete it? ( in green ) I scare when I delete it in this way will effect anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete that entry from:

- Site Actions > Manage Content and Structure

And if the links are still appearing you can perform an IISRESET.